# Issue with python installations

Tags: python, ubuntu, unix, networking

So last night I was updating python on my Ubuntu machine. And I had lost network connection. I thought this was strange considering my network shouldn't have much to do with programming language on my machine. But I tried `ifconfig wlan0 down : ifconfig wlan0 up` nothing worked then tried `sudo service network-manager restart` still nothing.

At first I had update "Pyhton" with `sudo apt-get install python` then I did `sudo apt-get install python 3` which I was just told by the I.T department in my school about that being called a side by side install and because of compatibility issues that I can not do that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3` You can have both installed.  When you do `python3 -V` will return the python 3 version your using and `python -V` will return the python 2 version your using

Comment: I know I can have more installed but it crashed my network manager or something and wont let me connect to any wifi it shows ssids even plugged into the ethernet but wasnt work my professor said maybe might be the network module

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? I have both installed and can use wifi

Comment: Also what is the output of `journalctl -u NetworkManager --no-pager`? And the output of `uname -a`?  logs usually provide hints